# Adding data based on the values of two or more other columns in R

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
 State         Name Population
1    NY     New York          1
2    NJ   New Jersey          2
3    CA   California          1
4    RI Rhode Island          1
5    NY     New York          1
```

I want to use R to sum up the population column for all unique combination of the state and name columns. So the end result will be:

```
     State    Name        Population
1    NJ       New Jersey           2
2    NY       New York             2
3    CA       California           1
4    RI       Rhode Island         1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dplyr package to do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(State, Name) %>% summarise(Population = sum(Population))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can just use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(Population~., df1, sum)
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(Population = sum(Population)), .(State, Name)]
```